# Why is date getting printed in the wrong manner PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am getting the date from the database and populating it in the textbox.

In my database, the date is stored in the following manner - `yyyy-mm-dd`
Default date stored in the database is - `0000-00-00`

```
<?php

    if($result['dob'] == '0000-00-00'){
        $dob = date('d/m/Y');
        echo '<input class="form-control" name="dob" value="'.$dob.'" id="datepicker" type="text">';
    } else{
        $dob = date_create($result['dob']);
        $dob = addslashes(date_format($dob, "d/m/Y"));
        echo '<input class="form-control" name="dob" value="'.$dob.'" id="datepicker" type="text">';
    }
?>
```

When I try to populate the date in my datepicker it shows the date to me in this manner - `01/01/-0000`

I wonder why is it printing the -0000. Please help.

Comment: Don't use `addslashes` to escape strings being put into HTML. Use `htmlspecialchars`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try writing `$dob = date("d/m/Y",strtotime($result['dob']));`

This will output your date from the database in the format of d/m/Y.